# Content Security Policy header in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-security-policy

Is there something else I need to do in a Rails app to set the CSP header in the API responses? I've implemented the module below but the header is not present anywhere:

```
# config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.img_src :self, :data, :blob, '*'
  policy.media_src :self, :data, :blob, '*'
  policy.script_src :self, :unsafe_inline, :unsafe_eval, '*'
  policy.style_src :self, :unsafe_inline, :blob, '*'
  policy.font_src :self, :data, '*'
  policy.connect_src :self, :data, '*'
  policy.child_src :self, :blob, '*'
  policy.frame_src :self, '*'
  policy.object_src :self, '*'
end
```

Comment: What rails version are you using? Did you restart the rails server after implementing this? How is your API implemented (e.g. are you using rails controllers or a separate library)?